Winking Out with polymorphic memory resources: efficient resource release and objects lifetime
I'm trying to understand "winking out" technique through examples (as I couldn't find, yet, a clean explanation). My goal is to acquire non-UB techniques that can be efficient when releasing resources.
Here are the examples (partially inspired from this post).
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory_resource>
#include <vector>

// if defined, the destructor of CallCounter (below) has a side-effect but may not be called, which is UB
//#define ACCEPT_UB

// dummy class
// the question is about the lifetime of objects of this class
class CallCounter final {
   public:
    std::size_t num = constructor_calls;
    CallCounter() { ++constructor_calls; }

    ~CallCounter() {
#ifdef ACCEPT_UB
        ++destructor_calls;
#endif
        // useless
        num = 0;
    }

    inline static size_t constructor_calls = 0;
    inline static size_t destructor_calls = 0;
};

// dynamically allocate a std::pmr::vector into a memory resource and let it go out of scope
auto winkingOut1() {
    std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource pool;
    std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator allocator{&pool};
    [[maybe_unused]] auto& winkedOutVector =
        *allocator.new_object<std::pmr::vector<CallCounter>>(5000);
    // both the vector and its data are in the memory pool
    // wink out memory on exit?
}

// create a local std::pmr::vector and explicitly "kills" its data by releasing its memory resource
auto winkingOut2() {
    std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource pool;
    std::pmr::vector<CallCounter> winkedOutVector(&pool);
    // only the vector data are in the memory pool
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 5000; ++i) {
        winkedOutVector.emplace_back();
    }

    // explicitly wink out memory
    pool.release();
}

// mere log
auto printResults(std::string_view description) {
    std::cout << description << ": " << '\n';
    std::cout << "\tConstructor calls: " << CallCounter::constructor_calls
              << '\n';
    // reset
    CallCounter::constructor_calls = 0;
#ifdef ACCEPT_UB
    std::cout << "\tDestructor calls: " << CallCounter::destructor_calls
              << '\n';
    // reset
    CallCounter::destructor_calls = 0;
#endif
}

int main() {
    winkingOut1();
    printResults("Winking out 1");
    // runs into heap-use-after-free according to clang sanitizer
    winkingOut2();
    printResults("Winking out 2");
}

LIVE
gcc output:
Winking out 1: 
    Constructor calls: 5000
    Destructor calls: 0
Winking out 2: 
    Constructor calls: 5000
    Destructor calls: 13191

clang output:
=================================================================
==1==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x531000014800 at pc 0x60a177381ed8 bp 0x7ffcfb87f460 sp 0x7ffcfb87f458
WRITE of size 8 at 0x531000014800 thread T0
    #0 0x60a177381ed7 in CallCounter::~CallCounter() /app/example.cpp:18:13
    #1 0x60a177381ed7 in void std::allocator_traits<std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<CallCounter>>::destroy<CallCounter>(std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<CallCounter>&, CallCounter*) /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/memory_resource.h:504:10
    #2 0x60a177381ed7 in void std::_Destroy<CallCounter*, std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<CallCounter>>(CallCounter*, CallCounter*, std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<CallCounter>&) /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/alloc_traits.h:935:2
    #3 0x60a177381ed7 in std::vector<CallCounter, std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<CallCounter>>::~vector() /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13.2.0/../../../../include/c++/13.2.0/bits/stl_vector.h:732:2
    #4 0x60a177381257 in winkingOut2() /app/example.cpp:57:1
    #5 0x60a1773813a6 in main /app/example.cpp:63:5
    #6 0x78f4b8029d8f  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x29d8f) (BuildId: 962015aa9d133c6cbcfb31ec300596d7f44d3348)
    #7 0x78f4b8029e3f in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x29e3f) (BuildId: 962015aa9d133c6cbcfb31ec300596d7f44d3348)
    #8 0x60a1772a8414 in _start (/app/output.s+0x2d414)

0x531000014800 is located 0 bytes inside of 65600-byte region [0x531000014800,0x531000024840)
freed by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x60a17737fa67 in operator delete(void*, unsigned long, std::align_val_t) /root/llvm-project/compiler-rt/lib/asan/asan_new_delete.cpp:173:3
    #1 0x78f4b8566ef2 in std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource::_M_release_buffers() (/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6+0x197ef2) (BuildId: 925fdbb642c48958ee86b4c067db1fd9baa5e4d8)

previously allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x60a17737ec22 in operator new(unsigned long, std::align_val_t) /root/llvm-project/compiler-rt/lib/asan/asan_new_delete.cpp:98:3
    #1 0x78f4b8566d21 in std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource::_M_new_buffer(unsigned long, unsigned long) (/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib64/libstdc++.so.6+0x197d21) (BuildId: 925fdbb642c48958ee86b4c067db1fd9baa5e4d8)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free /app/example.cpp:18:13 in CallCounter::~CallCounter()
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x531000014580: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x531000014600: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x531000014680: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x531000014700: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x531000014780: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
=>0x531000014800:[fd]fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd
  0x531000014880: fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd
  0x531000014900: fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd
  0x531000014980: fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd
  0x531000014a00: fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd
  0x531000014a80: fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd fd
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
==1==ABORTING

In first version , a std::pmr::vector and its data are allocated in a std::monotonic_buffer_resource and nothing is explicitly deallocated.
In second version only the data are in std::monotonic_buffer_resource, which is explicitly released.
Clang sanitizer is detecting a heap-use-after-free.
Is any of these versions a valid efficient way to release memory?
I'm feeling "bad" about both of them.
In first version, at first sight I would have say that there is a memory leak but maybe that pool destructor, called when leaving the function also deallocate winkedOutVector, but what's ending the contained object lifetime?
In second version, I've got the same issue with respect to lifetime and, I think that clang is right to complain because, on leaving the function, winkedOutVector will also be destroyed, trying to destroy its data that has already been destroyed by release. Am I right? If yes, how can this snippet be fixed? If not, why?
More generally, how does pmr work with respect to objects lifetime?

EDIT 1
A resource about winking out, see section 3 Available Concrete Allocators: Monotonic and Multipool. I think it might be the original proposal for pmr.

EDIT 2
cppreference on polymorphic_allocator documents several functions related to object creation or destruction (construct, destroy, allocate_object, deallocate_object, new_object, delete_object), yet I still don't see how the puzzle pieces are fitting together.

What is "winking out"? pool.release() (also called from the destructor) is ending the lifetime and releasing memory.

@rustyx, I don't see anywhere in std::monotonic_buffer_resource where objects destructor would be called or any mention of "end of lifetime".
As far as I understand, "winking out" is a way to wipe out a memory resources and the objects it contains without destructors calls and faster than through, for instance, classical uses of new and delete.
C++ weekly 250 and 252 are presenting the technique but it left me with above questionings. As I said, I found very few resources on the subject other than these examples.

A related link (but not a dupe)

"Clang sanitizer is detecting a heap-use-after-free" where?? Show us the output

Also if you could just show the printed output without forcing us to execute it on the Compiler Explorer, that would be nice
